# What is the name of this arc in English?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles, angle

In geometry, for any line segment AB and angle $\theta < \pi$, the locus of points $C$ on one side of line $AB$ such that angle $ACB$ equals θ is an arc of a circle. Points outside this arc form sharper angles than $\theta$, while points within this arc form wider angles.

In the Swiss school curriculum this arc is known as an "Ortsbogen" and the theorem that the locus has this shape is known as the Ortsbogen theorem.

https://en-academic.com/dic.nsf/enwiki/10100669

What is the name of this arc in English?

Comment: Do you mean major and minor arcs?  I guess the theorem is *angle in the same segment*

Comment: The french name is [arc capable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_capable)

Comment: The german name is *Fasskreisbogen*.

Comment: Seems that there's no single word for Ortsbogen; one may describe it as *the chord of the arc subtending the angle $\theta$.*